# D3.jsを用いブラウザからCSVファイルを選択して読み込む方法

Tags: javascript, d3.js

JavaScriptのD3.jsに関する質問です。
D3.jsにてCSVファイルを読み込む際、csvクラスを用いて読み込みますが、その際の第一引数はファイルの"パス"となっています。
そこで、ブラウザからフォームを用いてダイアログを開き、ユーザーのローカルフォルダから任意のCSVファイルを読み込みグラフの作成などを行いたいのですが、そのような動作は可能でしょうか。

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){
#ほげほげ
});
```

Comment: @rio.irikami
非常に丁寧な回答ありがとうございます、無事動かすことができました！

Answer (score 1):

d3は詳しくありませんので、グラフ処理などはご自身でお調べください。ローカルファイルの読み込みはd3にあまり関係有りませんね。ではドキュメントを見ます。

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV

> ## d3.csv(url[[, accessor], callback])
>
> Issues an HTTP GET request for the comma-separated values (CSV) file at the specified url. The file contents are assumed to be RFC4180-compliant. The mime type of the request will be "text/csv". The request is processed asynchronously, such that this method returns immediately after opening the request.

引数`url`に対して`GET`を発行し、ajaxでファイルを読んでパースするメソッドですね。
これを利用する、ということなら、ローカルファイルを`<input type="file" />`で選択して、ここから*objectURL*を生成し渡すというのがいいでしょう。
あるいは、ajaxでファイルの内容を読み込んでしまって、csv文字列を`d3.csv.parse`に渡すのも手段としてはありではないでしょうか。

サンプルを用意しましたので、適当なcsvファイルを用意してお試しください。

```js
var select = document.querySelector('#selectFileInputFile');
var view = document.querySelector('#view');

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
 var file = select.files[0];
  if (file) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    d3.csv(url, function (err, data) {
     if (!err) {
        view.textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<input id="selectFileInputFile" type="file" />
<pre id="view"></pre>
```